# How to reverse a text file

Tags: java, reverse

i have to reverse a passage of text in java. For example if the text file had

```
Hello world
This is a example
```

and you run java reverse input.txt output.txt, then output.txt contains

```
This is a example
Hello world
```

the code I have so far only reads the input. txt in the standard way. Any ideas on how to reverse. Im stuck

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args) {

        /**
         *  The name of the file and the location of the file.                  
         */
        String fileName = "test.txt";


        /**
         * This will enter one line at a time
         * FileReader reads text files
         */
            String line = null;

            try {
            FileReader fileReader = 
            new FileReader(fileName);

            // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
            new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }    

            /**
             * Closing the file.
             */
            bufferedReader.close();  


            }
            /**
             *Telling the program what message to show if the file is not found
             */

            catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Unable to open file '" + 
                fileName + "'");                
        }
            catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Error reading file '" 
                + fileName + "'");                   


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just use a simple stack of string type!

Comment: I think it helps to think about the problems in the real world before trying to code them. Write a list of words on a piece of paper. Try to reverse the order of words but only reading them from top down. When you've worked that out, there's a good chance you'll have created something similar to a stack. Then try to recreate the process using Java.

Answer (score 1):

You can  use a stack of string type.
add the strings to stack while reading the file:

```
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            myStack.Push(line);
        }
```

and read from stack at end :

```
bufferedReader.close(); 
while(!myStack.isEmpty()){
    System.out.println(myStack.Pop());
}
```

and some little changes on code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Recursion:

```
//firt you need have a method by allowing it to call itself
void tac (){
  /*local variable, change betweens calls because the language have his
    own stack that use for make calls at the methods*/
  String line;
  //end condition;
  if (line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
     //new instance  of method 
     tac ();
     //print the value of his local variable instance
     System.out.println(line);
  }
}
```

the first call use line("1") and call itself and make a new line ->line("2") this can  continue  ... line("N") 
when it get the end condition; Return in inverse order of calling, them  print line("N") this return...., print line("2") this return  and print line("1")

Comment: A brief explanation of how and why this works could make your answer more helpful to future readers.

Comment: [Recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#In_computer_science)